# MacBook Pro M1 Connectivity Issues with Dell U3219Q Display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-silicon

I recently bought a MacBook Pro M1 and using it with Dell U3219Q display. But If I boot the Macbook, the display can't find the connection signal, and it's closing itself automatically. For using display, I have to remove the USB-C from a port to plug in another port.

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 on the new Mac

It's weird; because I was using the same display with MacBook Pro 2017 model without any issue.

What's wrong with the new MacBook Pro M1 models?

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue.. Did you manage to fix it ?

Comment: @JoaMika Hi, yes. I solved the issue. I've replied the my own question below.

Answer (score 3):

The issue fixed by upgrading the firmware of the display to latest one. Dell released the firmware update app for the macOS and you can download it [from their support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/tr-tr/product-support/product/dell-u3219q-monitor/drivers).

[image]